# Why does counting up in recursive functions always require two parameters?

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp

I've written some simple loops with recursion and the loop macro but the thing that bothers me is that counting up needs two parameters and counting down doesn't.

Does an example exist?

The start of this question was just how to print something that increments up. The first function 'printsomestuff' was where I started.

```
(defun printsomestuff (stuff times) 
  (if (= times 0)
      'im-the-return-value
      (progn 
        (print stuff)
        (printsomestuff stuff (1- times)))))

(defun counting-down (topnumber)
  (if (= topnumber 0)
      'done
      (progn 
        (print topnumber)
        (counting (- topnumber 1)))))


(defun loopcounting (uptonumber)
  (loop for i from 1 to uptonumber
    do (print i)))

(defun recurcounting-up (uptonumber)
  (let ((incrementer 0))
    (if  
     (= incrementer uptonumber)
     'done
     (progn 
       (print incrementer)
       (recurcounting-up (+ incrementer 1))))))

(defun recur-counting-up-two (uptonumber startnumber)
  (if (> startnumber uptonumber)
      'done
      (progn
        (print startnumber)
        (recur-counting-up-two uptonumber (+ startnumber 1)))))
```

recurcounting-up infinitely loops with 0 because the reset of the incrementer on every function call. That is not what I wanted.

Comment: Should `counting` be `counting-down`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. One of your functions is just printing the number, the other is printing `stuff`. It needs two parameters because `stuff` is different from the number.

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether you're counting up or down, the difference is what you're doing at each step.

Comment: In the last function, you need two parameters because the end of the recursion isn't a hard-coded limit like `0`.

Comment: This question is very confusing. Can you cut it down to just two functions that show the difference you're asking about? One counts up, the other counts down, and they're otherwise identical. All the other differences obscure the problem.

Comment: @Barmar. uhh yes it should but the function works as desired so I didn't catch that. I think I used a lisp builtin?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what Barmar said ([his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57300472/5920214) actually answers the question, this is really a comment on it), if you use local functions then you *can* make the recursive function have only a single parameter.  You can even make it count in the appropriate direction.  But this is just a hack: if the base case or the step of some recursion is not fixed (ie are not always `0` & `1-` say) then you are going to have to provide them.

Counting in either direction in CL:

```
(defun count/printing (from to)
  (let ((next (if (< from to) #'1+ #'1-)))
    (labels ((count (i)
               (print i)
               (if (= i to)
                   i
                 (count (funcall next i)))))
      (count from))))
```

and in Racket, which makes it a little more elegant by being a Lisp-1 & having named `let`:

```
(define (count/printing from to)
  (define next (if (< from to) add1 sub1))
  (let count ([i from])
    (displayln i)
    (if (= i to)
        i
        (count (next i)))))
```

Comment: Yeah I realized that I could make a helper function inside my function, in cl with labels or in your example with let, but I was like, ewww.

Answer (score 9):

It has nothing to do with whether you're counting up or down. The issue is whether the base case of the recursion can be hard-coded in the function or needs to be supplied as a parameter. In your counting down examples, you always end at `0`, so it doesn't need to be a parameter -- you only need a parameter for the current number. But in your counting up example, the ending number can't be put into the code, so it needs that as a second parameter.

If you were always counting up to 100, you could code that just like your counting down examples. Similarly, if you wanted to count down to an arbitrary number, not just `0`, you would need two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

My solution looks like this after taking into account tfb's answer.

```
(defun recur-counting-up-two (uptonumber startnumber)
  (if (> startnumber uptonumber)
      'done
      (progn
        (print startnumber)
        (recur-counting-up-two uptonumber (+ startnumber 1)))))
(defun count-up (uptonumber)
  (recur-counting-up-two uptonumber 0))
```

It just creates a second toplevel wrapper function with one parameter passed in hard coded.
Although tfb's answer might seem more compact I find this to be more readable from a distance. Less center embedding is always a good thing in a language that does it too much already for readability.

Comment: Many Lisp people, me included, would consider a top-level function whose only purpose is to be called by another one, once, to be just a waste of namespace: it's something you have to do in languages which don't allow local functions, but that's what local functions are for.